# How to install sublime 2 in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: sublimetext

I want install sublime 2 in Ubuntu 12.10 via terminal. Anyone can help? And can I install Sublime packages via terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I wish SO hadn't banned LMGTFY. But here, this may help:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/582849/InstallingplusSublimeplusTextplus2plusonplusLinuxp

To summarize:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Answer (score 0):

**Install via Package Manager(apt-get)**

For Sublime Text 2:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

For Sublime Text 3:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Then run this command:

```
subl
```

**Install Manually(wget)**

Download from the Sublime site.

For 32-bit:

```
wget http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/Sublime\ Text\ 2.0.2.tar.bz2
tar vxjf Sublime\ Text\ 2.0.2.tar.bz2
```

For 64-bit:

```
wget http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/Sublime\ Text\ 2.0.2\ x64.tar.bz2
tar vxjf Sublime\ Text\ 2.0.2\ x64.tar.bz2
```

For both:

```
sudo mv Sublime\ Text\ 2 /opt/
sudo ln -s /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime
```

Source: http://www.tecmint.com/install-sublime-text-editor-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

```
**For Sublime-Text-2:**

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text

**For Sublime-Text-3:**
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```